# How to access a create-react-app from another computer?

Tags: reactjs, hosting, github-pages

I'm struggling on hosting my react app with github pages. (using create-react-app)

And It does not load data.json file.

How to access my react app from another computer?

I want to change this "localhost version" code for my purpose.

Is it sufficient changing URL part, say http://localhost:3001?
(Otherwise setting .env ... or using API ...)

I made some components files, and I attached App.js below.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";

export default function CreateDay() {
  const days = useFetch("http://localhost:3001/days");
  const history = useHistory();

  function addDay() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/days/", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
        day: days.length + 1,
      }),
    })
    .then( response => {
      if(response.ok) {
        alert("생성이 완료 되었습니다");
        history.push("/voca_app");
      }
    });
  }

  return (
  <div>
    <h3>현재 일수: {days.length}일</h3>
    <button onClick={addDay}>Day 추가</button>
  </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (if you want to experiment)
.You need to host your api's too.